# In an integral extension $A\subseteq B$, when $B$ Noetherian implies $A$ Noetherian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra, noetherian, integral-extensions

Let $A\subseteq B$ be an extension of commutative rings. If $B$ is a Noetherian ring and finitely generated as $A$-module, then $A$ is Noetherian ring.

> Is there any other such criteria, under possibly some additional conditions, which says that in an integral extension, if the above ring is Noetherian, then so is the below ring ?